# Can we use the Microsoft Speech API's speech to text functionality in MATLAB?

Tags: api, matlab, speech

Can we use the Microsoft Speech API's speech to text functionality in MATLAB?
 Here is the code for text to speech.How can we use the functionality of SAPI is speech to text?
For tts:

```
textIn = 'voice';
    ha = actxserver('SAPI.SpVoice');
    invoke(ha,'speak',textIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can by following a similar procedure to that of C# etc. using MATLAB's activeX server:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html

You need the first declare a speech recogniser engine

```
RC = actxserver('SAPI.SpSharedRecoContext'); %connect to speech engine
```

And then setup various call back functions for each state of the recogniser:

```
RC.registerevent({'Recognition' @CallbackFunction; 'Hypothesis' @CallbackFunction; 'FalseRecognition' @CallbackFunction})
```

The contents of the callback function should be along these lines:

```
function word = CallbackFunction(varargin)
    global word
    result = varargin{length(varargin)-2};
    word = result.Phraseinfo.GetText;
end
```

Then finally switch the recogniser on:

```
RC.Recognizer.State = 'SRSActive';
```

You would need to reference the documentation for which functions are called when
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(v=vs.85).aspx

You will need to also setup a grammar dictionary to get meaningful results. As the engine will be attempting to recognise any word otherwise.